# Replace elseifs with math

Tags: php, math, if-statement

My question is how could I replace those if's with math formula?

```
if ($l <= 3500)
{
    $min = 100;
}
elseif ($l <= 4000)
{
    $min = 120;
}
elseif ($l <= 4500)
{
    $min = 140;
}
elseif ($l <= 5000)
{
    $min = 160;
}
```

As you see this is raising 20 for every 500 levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As you see this is raising 20 for every 500 levels.

Well, that's your formula right there.

```
$min = 100 + ceil(($l-3500)/500) * 20;
```

- We start with 100, our base value and add that to the rest of the calculation.
- `$l` starts with 3500 less.
- We `ceil()` the result since we only want to jump when we pass the whole value.
- We multiply that by 20.

If we want to address the case where `$l` is less than 3500 and set 100 as the minimum value, we also need to asset that `$l-3500` is more than zero. We can do this as such:

```
$min = 100 + ceil(max(0,$l-3500)/500) * 20;
```

#### How did I get there?

What we're *actually* doing is plotting a line. Like you said yourself we go a constant amount for every constant amount. We have something called linear progression here.

Great, so we recognized the problem we're facing. We have an imaginary line to plot and we want integer values. What next? Well, let's see where the line starts?

In your case the answer is pretty straightforward.

```
if ($l <= 3500) {
    $min = 100;
}
```

That's our starting point. So we know the point `(3500,100)` is on our line. This means the result starts at `100` and the origin starts at `3500`.

We know that our formula is in the form of `100+<something>`. What is that something?

Like you said, for every 500 levels you're raising 20. So we know we move `20/500` for every 1 level (because well, if we multiply that by 500 we get our original rule). We also know (from before) that we start from `3500`.

Now, we might be tempted to use `$min = 100 + ($l-3500) * (20/500);` and that's *almost* right. The only problem here is that you only want integer values. This is why we `ceil` the value of level/500 to only get whole steps.

I tried to keep this with as little math terminology as possible, you can check [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) if you want things more formal. If you'd like any clarification - let me know

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. I wonder why it was downvoted.

Comment: Here is a [demo in JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/vjyde/) illustrating the formula at work.

Comment: In http://codepad.org/PlbU9ulJ this fails for 3629. Should be 120. Could you, please, fix this?

Comment: from 3501 to 4000 should be 120.

Comment: @Daniel in that case use ceil instead of floor http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php , I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Daniel glad I could help, I've added an explanation of how I got there.

Comment: Failed. I'm trying it (in python as that's more comfortable than PHP) and your function returns f(0)=-40 (instead of 100), <del>f(f(3499))=80 (instead of 100), f(3501)=100 (instead of 120)</del> (the latter was caused by python2's implicit flooring).

Comment: Aha, SO doesn't support 'del' sorry for the above comment. The only problem is that small values return wrong values, e.g. f(0) = -40.

Comment: Also, I'm curious why SO doesn't allow me to undo the down vote, everyone can make a mistake (in downvoting, in this case).

Comment: @PavelŠimerda SO locks your downvotes to prevent strategic voting. This is rather an annoyance. Don't worry about it as it was already accepted and I don't really care about reputation, the only important thing in SO is that relevant users get an answer that answers the question correctly and explains why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach about this problem. It's not better than a single-line formula, but for sake of being modifiable, I generally decide this kind of solutions:

```
$min = 100;
for($i=3500; $i<=5000; $i+=500)
{
   if($l <= $i) break;
   $min += 20;
}
//Now $min has got desired value.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can express the function as follows:

```
f(x) := a * x + b
```

The inclination of the line is calculated as:

```
a := 20 / 500
```

To find `b` you need to extrapolate a value that's on the line; in this case, that could be `3500` (x) and `120` (f(x)). That works out to be `-40`.

So the function has become:

```
f(x) := (20 / 500) * x - 40
```

There are two special cases:

1. Left of `3500` the value of `f(x)` must remain `100`, even though f(x) is less.
2. The inclination is not continuous but discrete.

Both cases applied:

```
$min = max(100, ceil($l / 500) * 20 - 40)
```